# How to update a project to another version of Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project, that was made for 18.102 version of Acumatica ERP, and after updating system to 18.105 version I have errors like this

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your extension library referencing Acumatica assemblies from build #18.105.0017? This is a pretty common practice to rebuild customization assemblies before an upgrade. And obviously, a mandatory thing to do when the upgrade is to the next major version.

Comment: I tried, but it isn't work and looks the same.